# How do I undo the local commits in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, undo

I accidentally committed the wrong files **to Git**, but didn't push the commit to the server yet.

**How can I undo those commits from the local repository?**

The only way seems to be to copy the edits in some kind of GUI text editor, then wipe the whole local clone, then re-clone the repository, then re-applying the edits. However,

- This can cause data loss.
- It's very hard to do this when only an accidental git commit was run.
- Is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+commits

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,
use the command git log to see all the commits.

```
git log
```

Copy the commit ID which you want to remove and then use,

```
git revert <commit-id>
```

to undo the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The command `git reset` will also help.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset